# Generating script for database schema changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two database schema. I need to generate the script consisting of the difference. How do I do this?

Basically, I had original schema that I modified. So I need the script for what changed. Which tables got dropped and relationships are broken etc...

P.S. I do not have red gate.

Comment: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have red gate.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2010+?

Comment: Yes, I have visual studio professional 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Schema Compare feature in Visual Studio:

```
Main Menu --> SQL --> Schema Compare --> New Schema Comparison
```

And go from there...

It may prompt you to download the SQL Server Data Tools [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015) if you don't already have it.

**Note:** I am no sure if this works in the Professional Version. It's certainly available in the Ultimate edition.

Comment: visual studio professional 2012 does have this tool. I had to add Data Tools recommended above.